# Ios DBAccess query debug

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, logging, dbaccess

I'm trying to debug query using delegate function

```
<pre>
- (void)queryPerformedWithProfile:(DBQueryProfile*)profile
{
    NSLog(@"QUERY: %@", profile.compiledQuery);
    NSLog(@"RESULTS: %i", profile.rows);
}
</pre>
```

but log shows this:

```
<pre>
2016-05-17 10:04:08.426 AppName[19301:410138] QUERY: (null)
2016-05-17 10:04:08.426 AppName[19301:410138] RESULTS: 0
</pre>
```

CompiledQuery and rows seems not initialized.
Do I need to enable debug? I'm using AppDelegate as delegate.

I need to debug query because I have a problem with a query containing LIKE clause:

```
DBResultset* result = [[[User query] whereWithFormat:@"type=%@ AND (name LIKE '%@%' OR surname LIKE '%@%')", @(kindId), strFilter, strFilter] fetch];
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with my query.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, that may be a bug in the profiler if there is an error, we'll test that and get it fixed ASAP if so.

But you want to be implementing the method:

```
- (void)databaseError:(DBError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@",error.errorMessage);
    }
}
```

To find any kind of syntax errors.  Also, you can just log out the profile to output a formatted query analysis like this:

```
- (void)queryPerformedWithProfile:(DBQueryProfile *)profile {
    if (profile.queryTime > 1000) {
        NSLog(@"%@",profile);
    }
}
```

With output like:

```
DB Query Profiler
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Query Time:1212 ms  Lock Wait:0 ms  Parse Time:0 ms  Seek Time:1211 ms  Row Count:1
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL Query
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SELECT DataForm.Id as result$Id, DataForm.completedDateTimeUTC as result$completedDateTimeUTC, DataForm.contentSetId as result$contentSetId, DataForm.submitted as result$submitted, DataForm.loginId as result$loginId, DataForm.resourceId as result$resourceId, DataForm.formData as result$formData, DataForm.submitGuid as result$submitGuid FROM DataForm WHERE submitGuid = ?  LIMIT 1 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQLITE3 QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Order:0  From:0  Usage: SCAN TABLE DataForm
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now:  To help with the LIKE command, you are best off using out `dbMakeLike(string)` function.  Used like this.

```
whereWithFormat:@"lower(text) LIKE %@“, dbMakeLike(searchString.lowercaseString)
```

This way the `LIKE` condition gets passed in as an object and we can treat it as a properly delimited parameter, without you guessing how we rearrange the queries internally.

Comment: Thank for reply! Does function "dbMakeLike()" perform char escaping?

Comment: It turns the parameter string into, ```xyz LIKE '%<string value>%'```.  But we need it to run it through the formatter as ```%%%@%%```, which would have been confusing to explain.

Answer (score 0):

For like query in 'SharkORM' you can pass query param directly like-this : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", searchParam] using objective-c.

Eg:
SRKResultSet *chanels = [[[Channel query] whereWithFormat:@"column_name LIKE %@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%%%@%%", searchText]] fetch];